# CSS - margin between elements without margin/padding?

Tags: css, margin

I've been working on my own CSS grid and found this website:

http://demo.select-themes.com/stockholm1/four-column-gallery/

Does anyone have any idea how it's achieved? Basically Portfolio elements have space between them, but there are no margins, paddings, anything I can think of:

```
<article class="mix portfolio_category_2  mix_all" style=" "><div class="image_holder standard_hover"><span class="image">(...)</article>

2% margin (not sure where it comes from!)

<article class="mix portfolio_category_2  mix_all" style=" "><div class="image_holder standard_hover"><span class="image">(...)</article>
```

I think it's Bootstrap but bootstrap's grid seems to have margins after all... These items have only bottom margins, but not right/left ones. How it's done?

Comment: Well, tke a look into your browsers development console. It should allow you to find out which css rule is responsible.

Comment: That's what I've done and there are no margins, paddings whatsoever...

Comment: Then how do you know it is 2%?

Comment: Becase 4 images * 23.5% = 94%, so it gives 6% for 3 gaps that come from I don't know where :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a rule styling the container:

```
￼.projects_holder {
  ...
  text-align: justify;
  ...
}
```

Try removing it in the development console.

Comment: Christ, this is brilliant. I was pretty much sure there's some JS-fiddling involved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :-)  Oh, and: "arkascha" is just fine, "christ" simply is too much.